# Execute stored procedure in Lightswitch 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm having trouble running stored procedures in Lightswitch on Visual studio 2015. Anyone mind give me any advice?

Kind regards

Comment: first question is how often do you need to run it, and secondly what is the stored procedure actually doing?

Comment: It takes parts of a table and inserts them into another table. I will need to run it monthly, but maybe weekly. I've gone through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635144.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3 and I think I might have it right all to the 4th point in "To invoke the stored procedure from a screen". I get this kind of display when i click on edit execute code: 
myapp.BrowsefactPhoneUse_bck2.UpdatePhones_execute = function (screen) {
    
};
And If I copy paste the code from the link I get many errors. Maybe I could give you a video of what I do or something?

Comment: A table called factPhoneUse_bck2 that has 5 columns: PhoneID, MonthID, KPI_ID, Value, Goal. My stored procedure has two parameters: MonthID and KPI_ID and once both are defined it goes looking into table dimPhones and takes all records with the same KPI_ID (they also need to be active) and inserts them into factPhoneUse_bck2, where phoneID is also a column in dimPhones, same goes for Goal. Values become NULL and monthID as well as KPI_ID is passed on as a parameter while invoking the stored procedure. Hope this helps in any way.
I'm promptly awaiting your reply and I am not asking too much.

Comment: currently anything I write after 'write code' is undefined...

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635144.aspx

Comment: this answer is exactly what you need, just make sure you are careful on where you add your stored procedure though, as if you put it in the general execute method, it will run every single time someone presses save (for every user)